# Finding where CSS and JS injection is called from

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, head

In my development site, I added an extension that I have since decided to remove.
Having removed all the files from the site structure, I am still seeing the css and js include files being included in the head of my page - at least the call to those files is there, as I have removed the actual files being called!

My assumption was that those css and js files would be added to the head via the xml files of the extension, and having removed those files, they would stop being added to the head, but they are still there??

I have not got cache running on the dev site (so sloooooooooow!!), but I still have flushed it anyway, several times!

Now I am scratching my head trying to figure out where these injections are coming from - if indeed I am not just seeing "ghosts" due to some other caching perhaps?

Is there some way to check what file requested the injection of a css or js file into the head of my page, so I can try to track it down and remove the offender?

Cheers!

Comment: This would have been added by a chain of xml files- the module declartion xml, the module configuration xmll, and the layout update from that module located in the theme. If you've removed these three files (or really, any of these files) then refreshing the cache should get rid of those injections. If it does not there is likely a file left over. It's possible they did not use standards and wrote a template override to 'inject' those files- in that case there is still a file left over. Either a remaining file or the cache, though. - Search all files and folders for the css filename.

Comment: Thanks Mikel - I found an XML file in the base>default config area that was injecting them - now removed! Cheers :-)